# C# - Custom Shell for Windows 2016 - Background does not change if explorer.exe is not running

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-server-2016

I am building a custom Windows Shell for Windows 2016, in C#, to replace Windows Explorer.

One of the functionalities of the new shell is to set the Windows Background/Wallpaper using a Windows (user32.dll) function called SystemParametersInfo(). However, the function only works when the Windows Explorer is running.

I noticed this behavior was introduced since Windows 8 and Windows 2012. So my question is: How I can change the Windows Background when the explorer.exe process is not running?

```
    public class WindowsBackgroup
{
    const int SET_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND = 20;
    const int UPDATE_INI_FILE = 1;
    const int SEND_WIN_INI_CHANGE = 2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN
    static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
    public static void Set(string imageFile)
    {
        SystemParametersInfo(SET_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND, 0, imageFile, UPDATE_INI_FILE | SEND_WIN_INI_CHANGE);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string appDataLocal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        string imageFile = appDataLocal + "\\Sysinternals\\BGInfo\\BGInfo.bmp";
        Set(imageFile);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would Windows GDI the way to go with my story? Maybe user32.dll always requires explorer?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-a-custom-window-background

Comment: I think I cant change the Windows Background using GDI, but I can create a full window as background and paint it. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, as you might expect, `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,...)` cannot set the desktop background when explorer.exe is not running. Creating a thread to display full-screen windows without borders may be another option, but you will need to redesign the entire windows desktop, icons, taskbars, file, etc., which will be a difficult process.